# Regular expression Hostname

Tags: java, regex

I am developing a http robot, and I developed this regular expression
`(((?:f|ht)tp(?:s)?\\://)?|www)([^/]+)` to detect and extract the hostname from a link (href).
Now I put here the results of the tests:

```
String -> http://www.meloteca.com/empresas-editoras.htm   
Returns   http://www.meloteca.com
```

```
String -> www.meloteca.com/empresas-editoras.htm    
Returns   www.meloteca.com
```

```
String -> /empresas-editoras.htm   
Returns   empresas-editoras.htm (without the slash)
```

In this case I was expecting that the regular expressions did not return any value? Why is this happening?
The same thing if I try with the following String

```
String -> empresas-editoras.htm   
Returns   empresas-editoras.htm
```

The snippet of code :

```
Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile("(((?:f|ht)tp(?:s)?\\://)?|www)([^/]+)");
        Matcher mat = padrao.matcher("empresas-editoras.htm");
        if(mat.find())
            System.out.println("Host->"+mat.group());
```

Answer (score 3):

It'd be better to use the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class, and its methods like `getHost()` and `getPath()`, rather than a regular expression.  The rules for constructing URIs are more complex than you probably realize, and your regex is likely to have lots of corner cases that won't be handled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove one of the question marks, like this:

```
(((?:f|ht)tp(?:s)?\\://)|www)([^/]+)
```

it should work better.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative `((?:f|ht)tp(?:s)?\\://)?` is optional, so it can be the empty string, and then `([^/]+)` just will match any string not containing `/`.